# How to Have Preprocessor Statements in Header File Depend on Which C++ File is Including It

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, header-files

How can I exclude certain #include statements in my .h file depending on which .cpp is including the .h file?

Example:

main.cpp file

```
<tell the header.h file that main.cpp is including it>
#include "header.h"
```

other.cpp file

```
<tell the header.h file that other.cpp is including it>
#include "header.h"
```

header.h file

```
<if called by main.cpp>
#include "some_file_which_fails_when_used_with_OTHER_CPP.h"
<end if>
```

Comment: In main.cpp, before including the header files, `#define MAIN_CPP`.  Then in your header files you can `#ifdef MAIN_CPP` or `#ifndef MAIN_CPP`.  But I recommend against this approach, for it is the path to madness.

Comment: Include what you need in the header file, and no more. Then, put the includes that your .cpp files need at the top of their files.

Comment: that's why  #ifndef is made of or pragma once i think a file is included once.

Comment: Did you consider *generating* your C++ file with e.g. [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) ?

Comment: Can you explain the motivation for wanting this?  [Possible XY problem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @Matt I am using Pybind11 to use C++ code from python, and the pybind11 compiler needs to include the pybind and numpy header files.  I want to use the same code accessed in C++ file too (without duplicating code and making it messy).  The pybind11 and numpy header files cannot be found for some reason when I call it in a normal .cpp file.  Frank's answer below worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to expect source files to `#define` a macro prior to including the header:

```
// the_header.h

#ifndef MY_HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_HEADER_H_INCLUDED

#ifdef MY_PROJECT_MAIN
// ...
#else
// ...
#endif

#endif
```

In files using the header's "default" behavior

```
// some_code.cpp

// Just use the header
#include "the_header.h"
```

In files using the header's activated behavior:

```
// main.cpp

// Make sure this is BEFORE the #include
#define MY_PROJECT_MAIN
#include "the_header.h"
```